# What is the velocity of an object sitting on the surface of the Earth in General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, velocity

In General Relativity an object on the surface of the Earth feels a force from the Earth due to the surface of the Earth's constant acceleration through space or space-time.
From what I've heard time is also at a fixed rate on the surface of the Earth.
The object cannot reach certain velocities due to Special Relativity, so there is a limit on the velocity but not on the object's acceleration.

Above is what I think I know and there is a velocity contradiction there. Feel free to ignore all of the above and just tell me what the heck is going on...

What is the velocity an object relative to it's local space-time while sitting on the surface of the Earth?
or well what is it's velocity with respect to anything except the Earth?

...I might know the velocity in reference to the Earth's surface but honestly I just don't want to hear that I'm wrong about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first state some general principles of the science of physics that I think are worthwhile to put emphasis on.

In science the global view overrides the local view. Not in the sense that the local view is irrelevant, it *is* relevant, but when you are assessing a situation as a whole the global view has priority.

Also, whenever you are assessing a situation the only meaningful assessment is the one where all available information is included. Conversely, if in your assessment you are leaving out available information then what you are doing is not science.

A natural way to organize views is in terms of bound systems.

All the matter of the Earth together is a bound system, and you can meaningfully take the Earth center of mass as the origin of a reference frame.

The Sun and planets of the solar system form a bound system, and you take the common center of mass of the celestial bodies of the solar system as the origin of a frame of reference for the motions of the planets.

Our Galaxy is a bound system, and you can take the common center of mass of the matter of the Galaxy as the origin of a frame of reference for motion on galactic scale.

Depending on what you want to investigate you choose the scale accordingly.

In the following it will become clear why I needed the above exposition.

Specific to your question about velocity.

As a matter of principle it is not possible to assign a velocity vector to spacetime. What does happen is that an *acceleration vector* is assigned to every part of spacetime.

Schematically:

- position vector: no
- velocity vector: no
- acceleration vector: yes

It is a fundamental *assumption* of relativistic physics that such an approach is possible. If this assumption would not be made it would not be possible to formulate relativistic physics at all. We have that is is clear that relativistic physics is a strong theory; on that ground the assumption is regarded as justified.

As you stand on the Earth's surface the local spacetime is accelerating relative to you. When you release an object to free fall the object co-accelerates with the local spacetime towards the Earth surface. As we know, locally this acceleration is indistinguishable from the acceleration of a spacecraft pulling 1 G of acceleration.

I now turn to the earlier exposition: *the global view has priority*.

For the Earth as a whole we have the representation that all over the Earth the acceleration vector assigned to spacetime is directed towards the Earth's center of gravity.

The global view overrides the local view: the global view is that the surface of the Earth is not accelerating with respect to the Earth's center of mass.

Bonus discussion

There is in fact something that you can to with a velocity vector. There is a way of assigning a velocity vector that will not give rise to self-contradiction.

Take the case of an object starting with zero velocity, from a point very far away from a gravitating body. As the object falls from far away it picks up ever more velocity. For every object that arrives at the surface that way: upon arriving at the surface the velocity is the same. The magnitude of this particular velocity is called '[escape velocity](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vesc.html)'

This is not to suggest that spacetime has a velocity; as a *matter of principle* no velocity vector can be assigned. It's just that if you assign velocity in this particular way then no self-contradiction will arise.

The gravity of a black hole is so large that if an object is released to free fall towards the black hole from far away then upon reaching the event horizon the object has been accelerated to the speed of light. If you would assign a veloicity vector to the spacetime at the event horizon of a black hole that velocity vector would be the speed of light.

Comment: Well there is only the contradiction that even though your accelerating everytime you measure your velocity is it always the same constant known as the escape velocity. Is there any source of material on General Relativity that gets into this type of analysis?

Answer (score 1):

*What is the velocity an object relative to it's local space-time while sitting on the surface of the Earth?*

As in Newtonian mechanics, an object's velocity can't be defined with respect to spacetime.

*or well what is it's velocity with respect to anything except the Earth?*

The word "local" from the first part of your sentence is crucial. GR has local frames of reference but not global ones. Your object has a well-defined velocity relative to any nearby object, and that velocity can be anything you want depending on the motion of the other object. Your object's velocity relative to some distant part of the universe is not a meaningful thing to talk about.

An answer by Claudio Saspinski says,

"If the surface of the earth were accelerating, the earth radius would be increasing, and it is not."

This is wrong. The surface of the earth is accelerating at 9.8 m/s2 relative to any inertial frame. Relativity defines an inertial frame as a free-falling frame.

The idea of the earth's radius increasing is based on Claudio Saspinski's misconception that GR has global frames of reference.

Comment: if you say that the surface of the earth is accelerating, without any mention of covariant derivative and curvilineal metric, it can be understood as the usual concept of acceleration. I presume the OP doesn't know that concepts, otherwise he would not be asking.

Comment: Can you explain why velocity cannot be defined but acceleration can?

Comment: Sorry, I have to downvote because "can't" is not an explanation, but if you change it just tag me and I'll undo do it sometime. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

In the frame of the earth, the object has velocity zero.

If the surface of the earth were accelerating, the earth radius would be increasing, and it is not.

What GR says is that locally, for example in a radius of 4km from us (more or less the distance to the horizon), all happens *as if* we were accelerating at $g$ in the space. But we aren't.

Comment: Can you expand on the "as if" for acceleration enough to explain why it has no effective "as if" velocity?

Comment: Btw, I didnt downvote. I think downvoting is completely counterproductive in most scenarios. Especially when no comment is left behind.

Comment: Velocity is relative to a given frame. In the frame of a region of the surface of the earth, the velociy of an object placed on it is zero. The acceleration, as change of velocity with time is also zero. But all that high school problems where $g$ is constant have the same results if instead of being at the surface of the earth, we were in a huge spaceship in outer space, under a $g$ acceleration.

Comment: So it is as if the object is at the speed of light and as if it's mass is going to infinity. Ignoring that, can you expand on what is behind the "as if" and why it has no "as if" velocity?

Comment: An object can be accelerated all the time that it will never reach the speed of light. The relation $v = v_0 + gt$ is only an approximation for small speeds (compared with light speed). Also for everybody in the ship, their mass doesn't change, neither the speed of light.

Comment: The statement “If the surface of the earth were accelerating, the earth radius would be increasing” is incorrect. It would be correct in a flat spacetime, but the spacetime around Earth is not flat. In a curved spacetime distant objects can indeed accelerate away from each other without the distance between them changing.

Comment: @Dale yes, but here I talk about $\partial ^2r/\partial t^2$, not covariant derivative. That acceleration is zero for any point at the surface of earth in the frame of the earth (not considering rotation).

Comment: Im more interested in what is behind the "as if" rather than the analogy of the spaceship. The ships mass is changing, increasing, as long as it maintains an acceleration per special relativity. It never reaches the speed of light but from other inertial frames it is approximately at the speed of light.